# Object(..) is not a function

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLmN4.png)

When I install the ant design to the angular project, I get an error as

```
Object(...) is not a function
   at platform.es5.js:102
   at Module../node_modules/ng-zorro- 
   antd/node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js (platform.es5.js:104)
```

Answer (score 0):

How you tried to install?

```
 npm install ng-zorro-antd
```

Comment: I installed it using Angular CLI

Comment: Please,give me a solution

Comment: Please share screenshot

Comment: I added screen shot above

Comment: Whis is your angular version?

Comment: This is my version  -  Angular: 7.0.4

Comment: Try to install this:  npm install ng-zorro-antd 7.5.1

Comment: I've got the same problem with v 8.x, angular 5.x